# Updating one row of MYSQL table at a time via button

Tags: php, html, mysql

I currently have a delete and update button next to each row of the table. The delete button works by removing that row from the table, however the update button only works for the last row in the table. If i attempt to change a field in a row before then and press update - it will update to the value of the last row... How do i fix this? (so that each row can be updated individually).

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {


                echo 
                "
                    <tr>
                        <td style='font-weight: normal;background-color: #ff9999;' class='row-time'>" . $row['topic_id'] . "</td>
                        <td style='font-weight: normal;background-color: #ff9999;' class='row-amount'><input type='text' name='up_topic_name' value='" . $row['topic_name'] . "'></td>
                        <td style='font-weight: normal;background-color: #ff9999;' class='row-amount'><input type='text' name='up_topic_address' value='" . $row['topic_address'] . "'></td>
                        <td><button type='submit' name='updateTopic' value='".$row['topic_id']."'>Update</button></td>
                        <td><button type='submit' name='deleteTopic' value='".$row['topic_id']."'>Delete</button></td>
                    </tr>

                ";



            }

            if(isset($_POST['updateTopic'])){
                $updateID = $_POST['updateTopic'];
                $updateTopicName = $_POST['up_topic_name'];
                $updateTopicAddress = $_POST['up_topic_address'];
                $updateTopic = mysql_query("UPDATE topics SET topic_name='$updateTopicName', topic_address='$updateTopicAddress' WHERE topic_id='$updateID'") or die(mysql_error());
                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
            }


            if(isset($_POST['deleteTopic'])){
                $deleteID = $_POST['deleteTopic'];
                $deleteFromTopics = mysql_query("DELETE FROM topics WHERE topic_id = $deleteID ") or die(mysql_error());
                $deleteFromUserTopic = mysql_query("DELETE FROM user_topic WHERE topic_id = $deleteID ") or die(mysql_error());
                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
            }

        echo "</form></table>";
```

Comment: where's the opening `<form>` tag?

Comment: Please note that `<form>` in `<table>` element is not allowed. You can wrap the entire `<table>` element in `<form>`.

Comment: ^ exactly. form cannot be a child of table.

Comment: Real nice SQL injection btw.

Comment: yes, that SQL injection and the same input name for each row made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

Both of the buttons are in form so they will always be there in the `POST` array

A quicker approach to perform edit and delete is done via `$_GET` request and make your links as

```
 http://localhost/project_name/file_name?id=".$row['topic_id']."&operation=delete
```

for edit:

```
 http://localhost/project_name/file_name?id=".$row['topic_id']."&operation=edit
```

on the server side, add this check

```
if(isset($_GET['operation']) && trim($_GET['operation'])=="edit")){
 // Edit code
}
else if(isset($_GET['operation']) && trim($_GET['operation'])=="delete")){
   // Delete code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML structure is not correct (tr > form > td is bad ^^) but it should be better this way. For a best structure, you should use div instead of table.
The idea is 1 action = 1 form :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['updateTopic'])){
    $updateID = $_POST['updateTopic'];
    $updateTopicName = $_POST['up_topic_name'];
    $updateTopicAddress = $_POST['up_topic_address'];
    $updateTopic = mysql_query("UPDATE topics SET topic_name='$updateTopicName', topic_address='$updateTopicAddress' WHERE topic_id='$updateID'") or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
}


if(isset($_POST['deleteTopic'])){
    $deleteID = $_POST['deleteTopic'];
    $deleteFromTopics = mysql_query("DELETE FROM topics WHERE topic_id = $deleteID ") or die(mysql_error());
    $deleteFromUserTopic = mysql_query("DELETE FROM user_topic WHERE topic_id = $deleteID ") or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
}

echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    echo "<tr>
            <form method='POST' action=''>
                <input type='hidden'  name='updateTopic' value='".$row['topic_id']."'>
                <td style='font-weight: normal;background-color: #ff9999;' class='row-time'>" . $row['topic_id'] . "</td>
                <td style='font-weight: normal;background-color: #ff9999;' class='row-amount'><input type='text' name='up_topic_name' value='" . $row['topic_name'] . "'></td>
                <td style='font-weight: normal;background-color: #ff9999;' class='row-amount'><input type='text' name='up_topic_address' value='" . $row['topic_address'] . "'></td>
                <td><button type='submit'>Update</button></td>
            </form>
            <form method='POST' action=''>
                <input type='hidden' name='deleteTopic' value=".$row['topic_id'].">
                <td><button type='submit'>Delete</button></td>
            </form>
        </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

NB : I moved out your update / delete action from fetch row coz you need to do it just once. With your code, you are, for example, deleting at each loop.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is because all the "name" and "adress" fields have the same input name...

when you try to read $updateTopicName = $_POST['up_topic_name'], what up_topic_name do you want? the one from the first row? the one from the second row? on submit, all the inputs named up_topic_name will be overwritten by the last value.

To solve this, you must name (only) the inputs up_topic_name and  up_topic_address like:

```
<input type='text' name='up_topic_name[{$row['topic_id']}]' value='" . $row['topic_name'] . "'>
```

and then when reading the value, do:

```
$updateID = $_POST['updateTopic'];
$updateTopicName = $_POST['up_topic_name'][$updateID];
```